WooCommerce Custom Backorder Message for Products with Variations
I was able to find some code on here to change the backorder message on WooCommerce. It worked really well. I then decided to use ACF to make it so I could have a custom message per product. This also worked well on products with no variations. On products with variations, it repeated this message for as many times as there are variations. So, if there are 3 variations, the message is repeated three times. Is there a way to make it only display once per product?
This is the code that I'm using:
function alt_message() {
  return the_field('backorder_message');
}

function backorder_text($availability) {
$altmessage = alt_message();
foreach($availability as $i) {
$availability = str_replace('Available on backorder', $altmessage, $availability);
}
return $availability;
} 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_availability', 'backorder_text');


function woocommerce_custom_cart_item_name( $_product_title, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
$altmessage = alt_message();
  if ( $cart_item['data']->backorders_require_notification() && $cart_item['data']->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
$_product_title .=  __( ' - '. $altmessage, 'woocommerce' ) ;
}
return $_product_title;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'woocommerce_custom_cart_item_name', 10, 3);


Where is the backorder message displayed and how?

I didn't change the location of the message, just what it says. It is below the product title.

what theme are you using? I can't see any message with mine.

There is a mistake in your code: Simply change return the_field('backorder_message'); with return get_field('backorder_message');. It should solve the issue.

I'm using Avada.

There is no issue with the message being displayed. The problem is that it is being displayed multiple times for products with variations. So, if a product has 3 variations (options), then the message is displayed 3 times.

You can't use return with the_field(), as the_field() display the field value using echo, so you need to always use get_field() with return!!!
